# Altium: Merge two polygons together

Tags: altium

I'm having trouble merging two polygons together; when I select them they have the same nets.

They are on the same layer and they have the same net, but they stay separated when I draw them. How do I merge them?

[image]

Comment: How are you "merging" them? What happens if you drag one so it overlaps the other? They won't merge automatically if that's what you were hoping for, you have to manually change the size of one of them so it touches the other, or better yet, get rid of one of them and use a single polygon for the whole thing. I know on the newer Altium editions, it (annoyingly) doesn't automatically re-pour a polygon when you change it's settings, so it may be that Altium hasn't updated the shape yet, see if repouring the polygon helps.

Comment: Derstorm answer the question. the problem was coming from parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your polygon properties (double-click on the polygon to open the "Polygon Pour" dialog), under "Net Options" make sure "Pour Over All Same Net Objects" is selected in the dropdown. Do this for both polygons. This should connect them together.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything was in the ""Pour Over All Same Net Objects" that's why it didn't work on my side !!!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to write a script that creates a new polygon pour that gets all the outer vertices of the original ones.

This means that you have to overlap them, and then determine which segments intersect, add new vertices at the intersection points, remove all the vertices that are inside the expanded polygon and feed these vertices into the software.

If the polygons are not overlapping, you cannot merge them because a polygon can only have one closed curve.

As you might have guessed from the description, this requires some geometrics as well as some good understanding of the scripting engine. I do not know of any build in feature that allows to automatically accomplish this. The only thing you can do is to manually expand the larger one to contain the smaller one and then delete the smaller one (as mentioned by @Tom).